# How to use manipulate to draw an image pixel by pixel?

Tags: manipulate, image

I want to draw an image pixel by pixel using `Manipulate`.
My code almost works but it erases the old points each time.

```
image0 = Image[Table[0, {x, 1, 512}, {y, 1, 680}]]

Manipulate[
  ReplacePixelValue[image0, coordList[[i]] -> 1], 
  {i, 1, Length @ coordList}]
```

`coordList` is the list of the pixels that get changed from 0 to 1 in the image.

Comment: you should show us `coordList`

Comment: Best for you to use your simpler solution rather than the answer that was posted given it was not acceptable

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, I need to post my answer, could you reopen the question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emptyImage = Image[Table[0, {i, 1, 300}, {j, 1, 400}]]

coordList=RandomInteger[{100,200},300,2];

Manipulate[ReplacePixelValue[emptyImage, coordList[[1 ;; i]] -> 1], {i, 1, Length[coordList], 1}]
```